# Deleting an item from SQLite and listView

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

i want to delete item from a listView and SQLite database with contextMenu (press on item and hold, delete button appears, press it and item deletes) and my code doesnt remove anything. I tried when pressed on Delete, toast with text appears and it worked.

**DBAdapter.java**

```
public void delete(String name)throws SQLException {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        if (db == null) {
            return;
        }
        String[] whereArgs = new String[] { name };
        db.delete("m_TB", "NAME"+ "=?", whereArgs);
        db.close();
    }
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
        menu.add("Delete");
    }

    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        String name = info.toString();
        if (item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
            db.delete(name);
            books.remove(item);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
        return true;
    }
```

**FULL CODE:**

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    ListView lv;
    EditText nameTxt;
    Button savebtn, retrievebtn;
    ArrayList<String> books = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    SearchView sv;
    /**
     * ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
     * See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
     */
        private GoogleApiClient client;

        final DBAdapter db = new DBAdapter(this);

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            nameTxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

            savebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveBtn);
            retrievebtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.retrieveBtn);

            lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1, books);



            registerForContextMenu(lv);

            savebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    db.openDB();
                    long result = db.add(nameTxt.getText().toString());

                    if (result > 0) {
                        nameTxt.setText("");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failure", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    db.close();
                }
            });
            retrievebtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    books.clear();
                    db.openDB();
                    Cursor c = db.getAllNames();

                    while (c.moveToNext()) {
                        String colIndex = c.getString(1);
                        books.add(colIndex);
                    }
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                    db.close();
                }
            });
            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), books.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            // ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to implement the App Indexing API.
            // See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information.
            client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this).addApi(AppIndex.API).build();



    }
        public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
            super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
            menu.add("Delete");
        }

        public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            super.onContextItemSelected(item);
            AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
            String name = info.toString();
            if (item.getTitle().equals("Delete")) {
                books.remove(info.position);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
            return true;
        }
    }
```

**DBAdapter.java**

```
public class DBAdapter {

    static final String ROW_ID ="id";
    static final String NAME ="name";
    static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    static final String DBNAME="m_DB";
    static final String TBNAME="m_TB";
    static final int DBVERSION='1';

    static final String CREATE_TB="CREATE TABLE m_TB(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
            + "name TEXT NOT NULL);";

    final Context c;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DBHelper helper;
    public DBAdapter(Context ctx) {
        this.c = ctx;
        helper = new DBHelper(c);
    }


    private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            try {
                db.execSQL(CREATE_TB);
            } catch (SQLException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            Log.w("DBAdapter","Upgrading DB");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS m_TB");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
    public DBAdapter openDB()
    {
        try {
            db=helper.getWritableDatabase();
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(c, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return this;
    }

    public void close()
    {
        helper.close();
    }

    public long add(String name)
    {
        try {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(NAME,name);
            return db.insert(TBNAME,ROW_ID,cv);
        } catch (SQLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public Cursor getAllNames()
    {
        String[] columns={ROW_ID,NAME};
        return db.query(TBNAME,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }

    public void delete(String name)throws SQLException
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
        if(db == null)
        {
            return;
        }
        String[] whereArgs = new String[]{name};
        db.delete("m_TB", "NAME"+ "=?", whereArgs);
        db.close();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not removing the item from the list `books`. If `books` is an `ArrayList` then
Change your line of code to

```
books.remove(info.position);
```

And to remove from database (If books is an ArrayList of custom type).

```
 db.delete(books.get(info.position).name);
```

And if books is an arraylist of string then

```
 db.delete(books.get(info.position));
```

Comment: My application is with Save and Retrieve buttons (When you press retrieve, all list appears). It deletes item, but when pressed Retrieve btn again, it appears again, so it means that it doesnt delete from database. When i tried to use db.delete(books.get(info.position)); it was "Unfortunately, library has stopped". I edited my post and inserted full code

Comment: It deletes but now i found one bug: For example i have 3 items to delete ("1", "2" and "3") i press delete on item "1" but it deletes item "2", i press delete item "2", it deletes "3" but if i press delete "3" application crashes

Comment: I dont understand what is happening :D

Comment: @Deividito try to use a longclick on your listview item and let a popup appear. Then create on the popup click the delete function. Then it takes only this one with the long click. Hope this helps